# Smallest degree of a polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, roots

What is the smallest degree of a polynomial with real coefficients and having roots $2w$, $2+3w$, $2w^2$, $-1-3w$ and $2-w-w^2$? Where $w≠1$ is a cube root of unity.
I can realize that the smallest possible degree can not be less than $5$. But failed to solve it by any method.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Hint: one of those is real, and two others are conjugates.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $f\in\Bbb R[X]$ and $z\in\Bbb C$ is a root of $f$, then $\bar z$ is also a root of $f$. *Proof*: $f(\bar z)=\overline{f(z)}=\bar 0=0$.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?